# Modifying global variable from onActivityResult() crashes app

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to allow the user to choose images, and then retain a list of paths to those images for later use.

```
public class NewEntry extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button selectPhotosButton;
    private ImageView imagePreview;
    private List<String> imagePaths;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_entry);

        imagePreview = findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);
        selectPhotosButton = findViewById(R.id.selectPhotosButton);

        // Select photo button listener
        selectPhotosButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                //startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Photos"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            final List<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();
            ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
            if (clipData != null) {
                for(int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++){
                    Uri imageUri = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
            imagePaths.add(imageUri.toString());

                    try {
                        InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                        bitmaps.add(bitmap);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } else {
                // Only one image
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                imagePaths.add(imageUri.toString());

                try {
                    InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    bitmaps.add(bitmap);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            new Thread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(final Bitmap b : bitmaps){
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imagePreview.setImageBitmap(b);
                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();

        }
    }

}
```

However when I try to add the image paths to the imagePaths list object from OnActivityResult it causes the app to crash after clicking the Choose Photos button. How can I retain the list of imagePaths? I need them to store in an SQLite database.

Comment: What is the error log that you see in the logcat?

Comment: Where does it crash? What does logcat say?

Comment: Apologies, it turns out I hadn't initialized the list and was receiving a null pointer exception. Thanks